# Accept user input while two calls are patched with dial extension

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I have an executive and incoming caller. I patched their call in Asterisk using the dial command, but how can I to receive the `inputi.e DTMF` from the caller?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at *features.conf*. It contains examples for:

> dynamic features

These dynamic features can be triggered by in-call DTMF.